# How to delete an extra space after the title in Org mode?

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

Currently I have it like this:

[image]

And as you can see, there is 1 extra space after the word "Titletest".

I didn't put it there, it can't be deleted in the file.

Emacs does that automatically for some reason.

Any idea what should I put into my .spacemacs config file to remove this additional space from the title?

UPDATE:

The video of the behavior looks like this:

https://i.imgur.com/aZgSqo5.mp4

Comment: I cannot reprodude it. Place your cursor on it and say `C-u C-x =` and add the results of that to your question.

Comment: Does it happen with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: I can't go on it it looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/aZgSqo5.mp4

Comment: So it's probably an apparent space that's added by the fontification. One way to deal with it is to not worry about it: does it cause any problems (other than the aesthetic one)?